# How to link a CSS file to a JSP with Spring Boot?

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot, jsp, jstl

I am using Spring boot starter web, and I am trying to link my stylesheet **style.css** in my JSP. How can I use the default configuration to link my css correctly ?

The following line in the `<head></head>` isn't working:

**>page.jsp:**

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" ></link>
```

Location of the files:

- **style.css** : /src/main/resources/static/css/style.css
- **page.jsp** : /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/page.jsp

[image: style.css]

[image]

Note :I can access my CSS using this address http://localhost:8080/css/style.css

On the other hand, using a JSTL tag **works** :

**>page.jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

```
<c:url value="/css/style.css" var="jstlCss" />
<link href="${jstlCss}" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Could someone explain me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare your resources in dispatcher-servlet file like this :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/static/" />
```

Any request with url mapping /resources/** will directly look for /resources/static/.

Now in jsp file you need to include your css file like this :

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Or if you want use Jstl just like this

```
<link href="<c:url value="/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Similarly you can include js files for your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try this this evening

Comment: I do not have such a file. Should I create one ? Since I a m using spring boot, I'd rather use a solution using the default configuration

Comment: @MeMeek Can you check my answer ?